# I made a simple chat room with sockets.io, how do I prevent XSS attacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

as the title says I made a simple chat room with sockets.io, the only problem is I have no xss protection and my buddies keep putting infinite loops as usernames, so you can imagine how trolly this is getting :P. This is my app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
var io  = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var usernames = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // When the client emits 'sendchat' this listens and  executes
  socket.on('sendchat', function(data) {
    io.sockets.emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
  });

  // When the client emites 'adduser' this listens and executes
  socket.on('adduser', function(username) {
    // Store the username in the socket session for this client
    socket.username = username;
    // add the client's username to the global list
    usernames[username] = username;
    // echo to the client they've connected
    socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected');
    // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
    socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected');
    // update the list of users in chat, client-side
    io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    // remove the username from global usernames list
    delete usernames[socket.username];
    // update list of users in chat, client-side
    io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
    // echo globally that the client has left
    socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
  });
});
```

How can I sanitize their input to prevent against such things, I tried googling XSS protection prevention, sanitize html input, and other things, but I can't find nothing!

Client Code:

```
socket.on('updatechat', function(username, data) {
  $('#conversation').append('<b>'+username+ ':</b>' + data.replace() + '<br>');
});
```

Comment: Throw away your `updatechat` emit and send the data.  Leave the presentation of that data up to the client.  On the client side, set the innerText of the element... don't just blindly put that stuff in HTML.

Comment: @Brad https://github.com/Gacnt/Sockets/blob/master/public/javascripts/socket.js#L12 How might I sanitize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, don't send that whole message from your server.  You are wasting bandwidth and mixing your presentation layer into your server, which will make things a real hassle later on.

Instead of this `updatechat` emit, try sending something a bit more useful such as `userDisconnected` with the username.  Let the client code display the message that the client has disconnected.

Now for your client, do something like this:

```
socket.on('userDisconnected', function(username, data) {
  $('#conversation').append(
    $('<span>').addClass('serverMessage').text(username + ' has disconnected'),
  );
});
```

The key here is that you use `$.text()` to set the innerText.  HTML becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks works great :D - New to sockets, I had no idea that it could directly show to the DOM like that